Netty Server Connection Drops
I have a multiplayer game server that communicates with Unity clients using Netty as the TCP layer. At some point (usually under heavy load), my clients' connections start dropping from the server, and they repeatedly attempt to reconnect. During this time, the server becomes unresponsive to them. Clients are unable to reconnect, and messages from active players are not sent to the server. Players experience a frozen state since their messages fail to reach the server, and server messages are not delivered to them.
My server has 16 vCPUs and 32GB of memory. When I check top, the CPU usage is around 300-400%. However, the cloud dashboard reports CPU usage as 20-25%, likely because the server has 16 CPUs. For database operations, I use a managed database hosted on another server.
I am struggling to identify the root cause of this issue and currently have no leads. Could you guide me on where I should focus my investigation to resolve this problem? I can provide my c3p0.properties, Netty initializer, and details on how messages are sent to Unity clients.
When examining thread-specific CPU usage, I notice that the nioEventLoopGroup threads consume the most CPU (around 30 threads, each using an average of 3% CPU, ranging from 1% to 5%).
c3p0.properties file
c3p0.initialPoolSize=20
c3p0.minPoolSize=20
c3p0.maxPoolSize=200
c3p0.acquireIncrement=10
c3p0.maxIdleTime=60
c3p0.maxStatements=2000
c3p0.checkoutTimeout=15000
c3p0.numHelperThreads=200
c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=300

Start Netty Server
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();     // sending 0 will set default number of processors
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrapTCP = null;
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrapWebSocket = null;
        Channel channelTCP = null;
        Channel channelWebSocket = null;
        try {
            logger.warn("Starting TCP server...");

            serverBootstrapTCP = new ServerBootstrap();    // (3)\
            serverBootstrapTCP.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)    // (4)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (5)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 6144)         // 2024-12-02 Increased from 4096 to 6144
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .childHandler(new SimpleTCPInitializer()) // (6)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (7)

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            int tcpPort = PropertiesReader.readInt("server.port", ServerSettings.DEFAULT_PORT);
            channelTCP = serverBootstrapTCP.bind(tcpPort).sync().channel();
            logger.warn("Started TCP server :)");
            logger.warn("Starting web socket server...");
            SslContext sslCtx = null;
            final boolean isSsl = PropertiesReader.readBoolean("server.ssl", false);
            if (isSsl) {
                try {
                    File cert = new File(PropertiesReader.readString("server.ssl.cert"));
                    File key = new File(PropertiesReader.readString("server.ssl.key"));
                    sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert, key).build();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception at setting certificate.");
                    logger.error(e);
                }
            }

            serverBootstrapWebSocket = new ServerBootstrap();
            serverBootstrapWebSocket.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)    // (4)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (5)
                    .childHandler(new WebSocketInitializer(sslCtx)) // (6)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 4096)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (7)

            int wsPort = PropertiesReader.readInt("server.websocket.port", ServerSettings.WEB_SOCKET_PORT);
            channelWebSocket = serverBootstrapWebSocket.bind(wsPort).sync().channel();
            logger.warn("Started WebSocket server :)");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException at startServers TCP.");
            logger.error(e);
        } finally {
        }

How I send messages to clients
public void sendResponseString(String str) {
        logger.info("O: " + str);

        boolean sendSuccess = false;
        synchronized (channel) {
            int i = 0;
            while (!sendSuccess && i < 5) {
                i++;
                try {
                    ChannelFuture cf;

                    ByteBuf byteBuf;
                    if (!isWebSocket) {
                        // Append terminate character on previous versions.
                        byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(str + '\0', StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        cf = channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
                    } else {
                        byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        cf = channel.writeAndFlush(new BinaryWebSocketFrame(byteBuf));
                    }
                    sendSuccess = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.warn("Text cannot be sent to ip : " + this.remoteIp, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

I'd be grateful for any tips or a direction where I can focus on.
Thanks in advance.

Did you try reproducing the issue using a low-spec development environment under heavy (artificial) load (i.e. stress-testing)? Couple that with additional monitoring (e.g. a Java Profiler/VisualVM) and debug-statements and you should be able to get an idea of what part of the server is causing trouble.
